# Create array from array

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this piece of code,

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die ("Error". mysqli_error($con)) ;  

while($res1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {       
    echo "<td>"($res1['date'])."</td>";
    echo "<td>"($res1['amount'])."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

It displays this data:

```
 2016-07-01 15
 2016-07-02 12
 2016-07-03 47
 2016-07-04 21
 2016-07-05 38
 2016-07-06 84
 2016-07-07 57
 2016-07-08 12
```

Now to want to generate another array from `$result1` to extract or show this data only:

```
 2016-07-05 38
 2016-07-06 84
 2016-07-07 57
 2016-07-08 12
```

But I do not want to modify this line

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1)or die ("Error". mysqli_error($con)) ;
```

Actually I want to extract some specific dates from array. i.e I want `date > 2016-07-04`

Is it possible to create array from other array?

Thanks

Comment: `if (date1 < date2) echo` But it is more reasonable to do what you want with SQL

Comment: Is it possible to apply SQL with $result1? I meaning getting data from with SQL from array.

Comment: Please post your $query. I think you need to modify it and add a condition..something like WHERE DATE(date) > '2016-07-04'

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraint that you don't want to modify the query, you have to use `mysqli_result::data_seek` for this. `mysqli_result::data_seek` will adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set so that you could iterate through it again, like this:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die ("Error". mysqli_error($con)) ;  

while($res1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {       
    echo "<td>" . $res1['date'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $res1['amount'] ."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

// adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set
$result1->data_seek(0);

// now iterate through the result set again, based on the condition: date > '2016-07-04'
while($res1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    if($res1['date'] > '2016-07-04'){
        echo "<td>" . $res1['date'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $res1['amount'] ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Here's the reference:

- [`mysqli_result::data_seek`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)